# Let the node tree to json in golang?

Tags: json, tree, go

I have  a tree  like the following, and want to save as json format?

```
package main
import (  "fmt")
type Node struct {
    Id string
    Nodes []*Node
}

func main() {
    node1 := Node{Id: "1"}
    node2 := Node{Id:"2"}
    node3 := Node{Id: "3"}
    node4 := Node{Id: "4"}
    node1.Nodes = append(node1.Nodes, &node2)
    node2.Nodes = append(node2.Nodes, &node3)
    node3.Nodes = append(node3.Nodes, &node4)
    fmt.Printf("node1: %p %v \n", &node1, node1)
}
```

the output json i want is like this ,and how to do it?:

```
{
  Id:"1",
  Nodes:[
         Id:"2",
         Nodes:[
               Id:"3",
               Nodes:[Id:"4",Nodes:[]]
               ],
        ]

}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like valid json to me. That said, did you take a look at [json.Marshal](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal)?

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do what you want:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Node struct {
    Id    string
    Nodes []*Node
}

func main() {
    node1 := Node{Id: "1"}
    node2 := Node{Id: "2"}
    node3 := Node{Id: "3"}
    node4 := Node{Id: "4"}
    node1.Nodes = append(node1.Nodes, &node2)
    node2.Nodes = append(node2.Nodes, &node3)
    node3.Nodes = append(node3.Nodes, &node4)
    fmt.Printf("node1: %p %v \n", &node1, node1)

    bytes, err := json.Marshal(node1)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(bytes))
}
```

This code will output json like so:

```
{
  "Id": "1",
  "Nodes": [
    {
      "Id": "2",
      "Nodes": [
        {
          "Id": "3",
          "Nodes": [
            {
              "Id": "4",
              "Nodes": null
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

*Notice, that if a Nodes field has no slice of *Node objects the field will be marshaled as a null value in the resulting json.  If you want the Nodes slice to render as empty, you will have to make sure they are initialized to an empty slice.*

Play with this code on the playground [here](http://play.golang.org/p/RtwRifxGM-)!